# How to use outer loopcounter to access an array in the inner loop

Tags: python, arrays, django, django-templates, django-views

In the code below the inner forloop is not working

```
<tbody>
  {% for rec in medrec  %}

    <tr>
      <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
      <td>{{ rec.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ rec.disease }}</td>
      <td>{{ rec.treatment }}</td>
      <td>  {% for n in medicine.forloop.parentforloop.counter0  %}
      {{ n.medicine }}
        {% endfor %}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

The code above generates a table. Each rec has a array of medicines.
Like for the rec.forloop.counter where forloop.counter == 1 there will objects in the medicine array index [0]. 
How do i print it?

```
def profile(request,rid):

    patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=rid)
    medic = MedicalRec.objects.filter(patient=patient)
    i=0
    a=[]
    for n in medic:
        a.append(medicine.objects.filter(Rec= n))
        print(a)
    if patient:
        return render(request,'patient.html',{
            'medrec' : medic,
            'pat' : patient,
            'medicine' : a
        })
    else:
        return 'patient not found'
```

Models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.TextField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    expiry = models.DateField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MedicalRec(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    date = models.DateField()
    disease = models.TextField()
    treatment = models.TextField()
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class medicine(models.Model):
    Rec = models.ForeignKey(MedicalRec,related_name='med_set')
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Rec.date)

class Billing(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    Date = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create the list yourself. Django creates a [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) for you. It will be named `medicine_set`, but now that you're showing your models you have overridden it to be `med_set`. So you do not have to create a list in your view. You can use the related manager in your template:

view:

```
def profile(request, rid):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=rid)
    medic = MedicalRec.objects.filter(patient=patient)
    return render(request, 'patient.html', {
        'pat': patient,
        'medrec': medic,
    })
```

Template:

```
<tbody>
    {% for rec in medrec  %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.disease }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.treatment }}</td>
            <td>
                {% for medicine in medrec.med_set.all  %}
                    {{ medicine }}
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: `    <tbody>
    {% for rec in medrec  %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.disease }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.treatment }}</td>
            <td>
                {% for medicine in rec.med_set.all  %}
                    {{ medicine.medicine }},
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>'

Comment: Exactly. Added your models to the question, from there we can see you have overridden the related_name.

Answer (score 0):

I modified melvyn's answer and it worked

```
   <tbody>
    {% for rec in medrec  %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.disease }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.treatment }}</td>
            <td>
                {% for medicine in rec.med_set.all  %}
                    {{ medicine.medicine }},
                {% endfor %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```